# Which phrase or word does “as” belong to?

Tags: grammar

> **As,** in order to will, it is necessary to be free, a difficulty no less great than the former arises: that of preserving at once the public liberty and the authority of government.
> <sub>Source: [Rousseau, *A Discourse on Political Economy*](http://www.constitution.org/jjr/polecon.txt)</sub>

Comment: Rephrasing it like this might help: *As it is necessary to be free [in order to will], a difficulty no less great than the former arises ...*

Comment: [The original](http://books.google.com/books?id=83Q3AQAAMAAJ&lpg=PA244&ots=4up6qEqJDZ&pg=PA244#v=onepage&q&f=false) says « Comme pour vouloir il faut être libre, une autre difficulté, qui n'est guère moindre, est d'assurer à la fois la liberté publique et l'autorité du Gouvernement. »

Comment: Your link does not work. And that translation is from some machine.

Comment: to will is horrible. And wrong. vouloir is to want or wish something.

Answer (score 1):

As Damkerng T. pretty much gave you in the comment, "as" in this case means "[like](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/like)" (prep. 2 b) or "[since](http://thefreedictionary.com/since)" (conj. 3).

> "Since it is necessary to be free in order to will..."

Answer (score 0):

*As* here means *because*, and it heads the clause

> As it is necessary to be free = *because to be free is necessary*

This clause is qualified by the clause *in order to will*, which is the complement of the adjective *necessary*—it expresses what freedom is necessary **for**.

The entire sentence refers to the Will of the People, which Rousseau talks about just before this. We may therefore paraphrase:

> The people cannot will unless they are free. This causes another difficulty (which is at least as hard as the difficulty we just talked about): how can the people be free AND the government have authority at the same time?

Comment: There's no question in the text.

Answer (score 0):

La première et plus importante maxime du gouvernement légitime ou populaire, c'est-à-dire de celui qui a pour objet le bien du peuple, est donc, comme je l'ai dit, de suivre en tout la volonté générale; mais pour la suivre il faut la connaître, et surtout la bien distinguer de la volonté particulière en commençant par soi-même; distinction toujours fort difficile à faire, et pour laquelle il n'appartient qu'à la plus sublime vertu de donner de suffisantes lumières.

The first and most important maxim of legitimate government or a people's government, that is, one the object of which is the good of its people, is thus, as I have said, to follow in full the general will, but in order to do so, it must be known, and above all, it must be distinguished from specific will, starting with ones own will; a distinction always very difficult to make, and for which only the most sublime virtue may shed sufficient light on.

Comme pour vouloir il faut être libre, une autre difficulté qui n'est guère moindre, est **d'assurer** à la fois la liberté publique et l'autorité du gouvernement.
Original French

Since in order to have will [or to want something], one must be free, another difficulty which is not lesser in nature than this, is to **ensure** both public liberty and government authority.
*My translation*

assurer is not preserve: it means to ensure

vouloir is to want something or will, volonté is will [as in to have the will to do something]

[Text in French](http://classiques.uqac.ca/classiques/Rousseau_jj/discours_economie_politique/discours_eco_pol.html)

**As** or **since** are causal conjunctions.